# Proxy inverso con NGIX

Tags: linux, servidor, nginx, debian, proxy

actualmente tengo virtualizado un servidor en proxmox con la siguiente configuracion

```
IP PRIVADA : 172.18.2.201 que apunta a IP PUBLICA : 200.7.168.48
```

ahora instale nginx y quiero usarlo como proxy inverso para dos nuevas maquinas virtuales que tienen instalados dos servicios de apache distintos, que cree

```
IP PRIVADA 1: 172.18.2.202   y  IP PRIVADA 2: 172.18.2.203
```

Actualmente no cuento con dominios, seria posible configurar el nginx como proxy inverso para que al colocar `200.7.168.48/aplicacion1 envie a 172.18.2.202` y `200.7.168.48/aplicacion2 envia a 172.18.2.203`
la configuraciion es muy confusa cuando se usa con dominios.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? Si tienes configurado el proxy reverso, esto debería funcionar: `location /aplicacion1 { proxy_pass http://172.18.2.202 }` lo mismo para la otra redirección. Todo está en la [documentación](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/#pass) de *nginx*. Asumo que las máquinas virtuales se ven entre si dentro de la red privada. Saludos